# Stack / Unstack not preserving the data order in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have json data below

```
[[{"value":"ZZ","formattedValue":"ZZ"},{"value":"In","formattedValue":"In"},{"value":"Amount1","formattedValue":"Amount1"},{"value":"100","formattedValue":"100"}],[{"value":"ZZ","formattedValue":"ZZ"},{"value":"In","formattedValue":"In"},{"value":"Amount2","formattedValue":"Amount2"},{"value":"200","formattedValue":"200"}],[{"value":"ZZ","formattedValue":"ZZ"},{"value":"Out","formattedValue":"Out"},{"value":"Amount1","formattedValue":"Amount1"},{"value":"30","formattedValue":"30"}],[{"value":"ZZ","formattedValue":"ZZ"},{"value":"Out","formattedValue":"Out"},{"value":"Amount2","formattedValue":"Amount2"},{"value":"4","formattedValue":"40"}],[{"value":"CC","formattedValue":"CC"},{"value":"In","formattedValue":"In"},{"value":"Amount1","formattedValue":"Amount1"},{"value":"100","formattedValue":"100"}],[{"value":"CC","formattedValue":"CC"},{"value":"In","formattedValue":"In"},{"value":"Amount2","formattedValue":"Amount2"},{"value":"200","formattedValue":"200"}],[{"value":"CC","formattedValue":"CC"},{"value":"Out","formattedValue":"Out"},{"value":"Amount1","formattedValue":"Amount1"},{"value":"30","formattedValue":"30"}],[{"value":"CC","formattedValue":"CC"},{"value":"Out","formattedValue":"Out"},{"value":"Amount2","formattedValue":"Amount2"},{"value":"4","formattedValue":"40"}]]
```

In the table format, it should look like below,

| Dimension | Type | Amount1 | Amount2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ZZ | In | 100 | 200 |
| ZZ | Out | 30 | 40 |
| CC | In | 100 | 200 |
| CC | Out | 30 | 40 |

howerver, if I convert the json using python code below, the order in which the incoming data came is not preserved.

```
data  = 'jsondata'
data  = json.loads(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data).stack().map(lambda x:x.get('formattedValue')).unstack()
df.columns =['Type','InOut','MeasureName','MeasureValue']
df = df.pivot_table(index=['Type','InOut'],columns=['MeasureName'],values="MeasureValue",aggfunc='sum').reset_index()
```

the output of this is below. If you look at it, the dimension is ordered. I dont want it to happen. I have to keep the order of the data same as it came in. How to achieve this please? Thanks.

| Dimension | Type | Amount1 | Amount2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CC | In | 100 | 200 |
| CC | Out | 30 | 40 |
| ZZ | In | 100 | 200 |
| ZZ | Out | 30 | 40 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {
            "Dimension": subl1[0]["formattedValue"],
            "Type": subl1[1]["formattedValue"],
            "Amount1": subl1[-1]["formattedValue"],
            "Amount2": subl2[-1]["formattedValue"],
        }
        for subl1, subl2 in zip(data[::2], data[1::2])
    ]
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Dimension Type Amount1 Amount2
0        ZZ   In     100     200
1        ZZ  Out      30      40
2        CC   In     100     200
3        CC  Out      30      40
```

Comment: It worked and it is simpler version. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

You can try:

before pivot_table create a variable:

```
uni=df['Type'].unique()
```

after pivoting use:

```
df=df.loc[df['Type'].map(dict(zip(uni,range(len(uni))))).sort_values().index]
```

output of `df`:

```
MeasureName     Type        InOut
  2             ZZ              In
  3             ZZ              Out
  0             CC              In
  1             CC              Out
```

Comment: Thank you. I have a situation where the order (uniqueness) should be based on 3 columns. How can I use your code in that scenario please?

Comment: @Muthu without seeing your df and condition I can't tell!!!

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution: clean the data before putting it to pandas:

```
data = json.loads(s)
data = list(map(lambda row: [el.get('formattedValue') for el in row], data))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Dimension', 'Type', 'Amount1', 'Amount2'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's go back a few steps.

First start with `pd.json_normalize` to read in the json arrays.

Let's assume your json is called `d` you can replace it with your path:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(i).drop('value',1) for i in d])
```

Now let's create a new index so we can unstack without a duplication error:

```
df1 = df.set_index(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(),append=True).unstack(0).droplevel(0,1)
```

---

```
print(df1)

    0    1        2    3
0  ZZ   In  Amount1  100
1  ZZ   In  Amount2  200
2  ZZ  Out  Amount1   30
3  ZZ  Out  Amount2   40
4  CC   In  Amount1  100
5  CC   In  Amount2  200
6  CC  Out  Amount1   30
7  CC  Out  Amount2   40
```

Okay we are close, let's create your pivot and assign your column names:

```
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df1,
                    index=[0,1], columns=[2], values=               
                    [3],aggfunc='first').reset_index().droplevel(0,1
                    )

df2.columns = ['Dimension','Type','Amount1','Amount2']

print(df2)

  Dimension Type Amount1 Amount2
0        CC   In     100     200
1        CC  Out      30      40
2        ZZ   In     100     200
3        ZZ  Out      30      40
```